# Multi-valued properties with Frame annotations

Tags: tinkerpop

I'm trying to figure out how to support multi-valued properties with the Tinkerpop Frames API. I have an interface like this:

```java
interface Node {

  @Property("synonyms")
  public Iterable<String> getSynonyms();

  @Property("synonyms")
  public void addSynonym(String synonyms);

}
```

The `addSynonym` call doesn't throw any exceptions but the `getSynonyms` alyways returns `null`. I also tried switching `Iterable` to `Collection` with no change.

Does Frames support multi-valued properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Property in Frames does not support collection semantics as Tinkerpop 2.x does not allow this. It simply gets or sets the property on the underlying element.

The method prefixes supported for @Property are get, is, can, set and remove
https://github.com/tinkerpop/frames/wiki/Core-Annotations

You could write your own method handler that supports this:
https://github.com/tinkerpop/frames/wiki/Method-Handlers